# Magento2 Read PDF data

Tags: magento2, pdf

Magento2 How can I read data from PDF file. The product data is in the form of table inside a PDF file. I need get the data & then make some changes

Comment: Default magento dose not have any functionality to read data from the PDF, I think you should have to look for any third party AI service.

Answer (score 0):

This website describe a method for read a PDF with PHP but if you need specific data in PDF use this and a regex for grep specific part.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-pdf-file-using-php/